# Unity build error: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an script **Item.cs** that is responsible for setting the parameters of an item in the player's inventory. In it, I connect the Unity Editor library and create a class that inherits from the Editor class. Until recently I was using Unity version **2020.3.0f1** where everything was building fine, but now I installed **2021.3.9f1** and I started having problems.

**When I build the project, I get the following errors:**

Assets\Inventory\Items.cs(31,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Editor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Inventory\Items.cs(30,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditorAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Inventory\Items.cs(30,5): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\Inventory\Items.cs(32,28): error CS0115: 'Items.ItemsEditor.OnInspectorGUI()': no suitable method found to override

**Code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class Items : MonoBehaviour {
   public enum itemTypes { Weapon, Potion, Amulet }
   public enum potionType { Health, Poison, Strong, Beer }
   public enum amuletType { Health, Defense, Speed }

   [Header("Main Settings")]
   public itemTypes ItemTypes;
   [HideInInspector] public GameObject Model;
   [HideInInspector] public Texture2D Icon;
   [HideInInspector] public string itemName;
   [HideInInspector] public int itemNum;

   // Weapon
   [HideInInspector] public float damage;
   [HideInInspector] public float atackSpeed;
   [HideInInspector] public int broken;

   // Potion
   [HideInInspector] public potionType Potion = potionType.Health;
   [HideInInspector] public float healthOfset;
   [HideInInspector] public bool processingEffect;

   // Amulet
   [HideInInspector] public amuletType Amulet = amuletType.Health; 
   [HideInInspector] public float amuletValue;
    
   [CustomEditor(typeof(Items))]
   public class ItemsEditor : Editor {
      public override void OnInspectorGUI() {
         base.OnInspectorGUI();
         Items items = (Items) target;
         DrawMain(items);
         EditorGUILayout.Space();
      
         switch (items.ItemTypes) {
            case itemTypes.Weapon:
               WeaponSettings();
               break;
            case itemTypes.Potion:
               PotionSettings();
               break;
            case itemTypes.Amulet:
               AmuletSettings();
               break;
         }
         serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
      }

      void DrawMain(Items items) {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Icon"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Model"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("itemNum"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("itemName"));
         EditorGUILayout.Space();
      }

      void WeaponSettings() {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("damage"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("atackSpeed"));
      }

      void PotionSettings() {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Potion"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("healthOfset"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("processingEffect"));
      }

      void AmuletSettings() {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("Amulet"));
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("amuletValue"));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to put the script in a folder called Editor so like Plugins it knows what to do with it as the Editor Isnt available in the build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the name suggests the `UnityEditor` namespace is only available within the Unity editor itself an completely stripped of / simply not included when compiling a build.

There is usually three ways of preventing editor code to be compiled during a build

- Put your filed in a folder called `Editor` - This entire content is ignored during a build (see also [Special Folder Names](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html))
- Put your code into a folder with an [Assembly Definition](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html) which is only compiled for the editor and no other target platform
- Use [Conditional Compilation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

In your case the simplest way would be to wrap everything related to the `UnityEditor` namespace in according [`#if - #endif` pre-processors](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives#conditional-compilation) since you embedded the editor into the type itself.

I usually would prefer the same btw since having the editor embedded yields some advantages imho:

- You can directly use `nameof` instead of hardcoded strings -> error prone and maintenance intense
- You have access to even private serialized fields => can again use `nameof` even for those
- You immediately know that for this type a custom editor exists and where to find it which is not that trivial when strictly separating them

*I would btw not touch the `target` directly but completely go through `serializedObject`.*

```
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_EDITOR // => Ignore from here to next endif if not in editor
using UnityEditor;
#endif

public class Items : MonoBehaviour 
{
   public enum itemTypes { Weapon, Potion, Amulet }
   public enum potionType { Health, Poison, Strong, Beer }
   public enum amuletType { Health, Defense, Speed }

   [Header("Main Settings")]
   public itemTypes ItemTypes;
   public GameObject Model;
   public Texture2D Icon;
   public string itemName;
   public int itemNum;

   // Weapon
   public float damage;
   public float atackSpeed;
   public int broken;

   // Potion
   public potionType Potion = potionType.Health;
   public float healthOfset;
   public bool processingEffect;

   // Amulet
   public amuletType Amulet = amuletType.Health; 
   public float amuletValue;
    
#if UNITY_EDITOR // => Ignore from here to next endif if not in editor
   [CustomEditor(typeof(Items))]
   public class ItemsEditor : Editor 
   {
      private SeriaizdProperty itemTypes;
      private SeriaizdProperty icon;
      private SeriaizdProperty model;
      private SeriaizdProperty itemNum;
      private SeriaizdProperty itemName;
      private SeriaizdProperty damage;
      private SeriaizdProperty atackSpeed;
      private SeriaizdProperty potion;
      private SeriaizdProperty healthOfset;
      private SeriaizdProperty processingEffect;
      private SeriaizdProperty amulet;
      private SeriaizdProperty amuletValue;
      

      private void OnEnable()
      {
          // it is enough to do these ONCE when the inspector is loaded

          // note that one huge advantage of having the Editor embedded into your class is that you can 
          // - and imho SHOULD - directly use "nameof" instead of going by hardcoded strings (-> error prone and maintenance intense)
          itemTypes = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(ItemTypes));
          icon = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(Icon));
          model = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(model));
          itemNum = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(itemNum));
          itemName = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(itemName));
          damage = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(damage));
          atackSpeed = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(atackSpeed));
          potion = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(Potion));
          healthOfset = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(healthOfset));
          processingEffect = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(processingEffect));
          amulet = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(Amulet));
          amuletValue = serializedObject.FindProperty(nameof(amuletValue));
      }

      public override void OnInspectorGUI() 
      {
         //base.OnInspectorGUI();

         // This is also required so the serialized poperties get updated
         // with the current actual values
         serializedObject.Update();

         DrawMain(items);
         EditorGUILayout.Space();
      
         switch (items.ItemTypes) 
         {
            case itemTypes.Weapon:
               WeaponSettings();
               break;

            case itemTypes.Potion:
               PotionSettings();
               break;

            case itemTypes.Amulet:
               AmuletSettings();
               break;
         }

         serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
      }

      void DrawMain(Items items) 
      {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(icon);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(model);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemNum);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(itemName);
         EditorGUILayout.Space();
      }

      void WeaponSettings() 
      {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(damage);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(atackSpeed);
      }

      void PotionSettings() 
      {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(potion);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(healthOfse);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(processingEffect);
      }

      void AmuletSettings() 
      {
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(amulet);
         EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(amuletValue);
      }
   }
#endif
}
```

---

#### However

Now allow me to ask: **Why not rather use proper inheritance and do the following without the need for any custom editor at all?**

```
public abstract class Items : MonoBehaviour 
{
   [Header("Main Settings")]
   public GameObject Model;
   public Texture2D Icon;
   public string itemName;
   public int itemNum;
}
```

and then (each in individual script files of course)

```
public class Weapon : Items
{
   [Header("Weapon Settings")]
   public float damage;
   public float atackSpeed;
   public int broken;
}

public class Potion : Items
{
    public enum PotionType { Health, Poison, Strong, Beer }

    [Header("Potion Settings")]
    public PotionType potionType;
    public float healthOfset;
    public bool processingEffect;
}

public class Amulet : Items
{
    public enum AmuletType { Health, Defense, Speed }

    [Header("Amulet Settings")]
    public AmuletType amuletType; 
    public float amuletValue;
}
```

Now whenever you need to differ between different items you simply do

```
Items item = <Get from somewhere>;
switch(item)
{
    // This combines a type check and casting to the according type
    // in one go. Basically similar to former using 
    // if(item is Weapon weapon){ ... } else if(item is Potion potion) { ... }
    case Weapon weapon:
        // do something with a weapon e.g.
        Debug.Log($"weapon damage = {weapon.damage}", item);
        break;

    case Potion potion:
        // do something if it is a potion
        Debug.Log($"potion type = {potion.potionType}", item);
        break;

    case Amulet amulet:
        // do something if it is an amulet
        Debug.Log($"amulet type = {amulet.amuletType}", item);
        break;

    default:
        // a type you haven't handled so far -> either ignore or implement properly
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"Type {item.GetType.AssemblyQualifiedName} is not handled yet!");
        break;
}
```

---

And finally, does this need to be a `MonoBehaviour`? It seems like this could ether be a [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html) or just a generic

```
[Serializable] 
public class Items 
{ 
    ... 
}
```

for which you would then rather implement a custom [`PropertyDrawer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-PropertyDrawers.html)

Comment: great answer! well done.

Comment: How come unity does not output this error specifically rather than very ambitious error. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Teomanshipahi tbh the error is as explicit as c# in general gets ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to inherit `Editor`.

In the class line you should replace it with `MonoBehaviour`.

```
public class Items : Editor {
```

Note that now this script is not a `MonoBehaviour`, so it will not let you do certain things. For example, Update and Start may not be called.

**(In your case you may not need this)** If your current class needs to be a MonoBehaviour, I would reccomend a new class that inherits the Editor and keep this one the same. You can do all gui in the new class.

---

TL;DR Inherit `Editor`.

```
public class Items : Editor {
```

Comment: When I changed MonoBehaivour to Editor I got a lot of errors. All the same it is necessary to create a separate class. However, I don't really understand how to do it. Could you guide me?

Comment: just replace the first line with what I said in the code. Can you say what errors you are getting

Comment: OP already **has** an embedded class `ItemsEditor : Editor` .. the issue is rather that the entire namespace `UnityEditor` will be stripped of during the build process